# Unable to Merge feature branch into Master as files are getting deleted? How to retain changes?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Consider timelines t1 < t2 < t3.

On t1 => branch A had been created from master. and file1 and file2 have been created and committed in branch A

On t2 => branch A had been merged into master and after the merge, file1 and file2 had been deleted and committed on master.

On t3 => Tried merging branch A into to master, but file1 and file2 are not found (deleted?) in master after the merge (there were no conflicts being thrown)

How to merge or do any set of necessary steps to retain file1 and file2 on master after merge/necessary steps completion?

1. Tried Merging branch A into master, file1 and file2 are not found (deleted) in master after the merge
2. Tried Rebasing branch A into master, file1 and file2 are not found (deleted) in master after the rebase

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there are new commits in `branchA` after merging into `master`? But they *do not* mess up with `file1` nor `file2`, right? Then what you are seeing is expected to happen. After you merged `branchA` into `master` the first time, you had something line this:

```
A <- B <- D <- E <- (master)
     ^        /
      \- C <-/
         ^
         \- (branchA)
```

You can see how `branchA` has been merged into `master`. Say that there was one new commit on `master` that deleted the 2 files, and then there is a couple of new commits in `branchA` that *do not* mess up with the files:

```
A <- B <- D <- E <- F <- (master)
     ^        /
      \- C <-/
         ^
         \- G <- H <- (branchA)
```

Now, if you tried to merge `branchA` into `master`, you need to consider that the last *common* ancestor in this merge is `C`, not `B` as it was before.... *and* in `C..H`, there are no changes in the files that were deleted in `F` and so a merge would not conflict at all nor will you find that the files will show up in the result of the merge.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I understand the behaviour now, I do not have enough rep to upvote your answer. I plan to just copy the files from branch A now and paste them into master and commit them.